# How do I grep a string on multiple files only if the string is present in all of all the files?

Tags: linux, file, grep

I have around 20 files. The first columns of each file contains ids (ID0001, ID0056, ID0165 etc). I have a list file that contains all possible ids. I want to find the ids from that file that are present in all the files. Is there a way to use grep for this? So far if I use the command:

```
grep "id_name" file*.txt,
```

it prints the id even if it is present in only 1 file.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable truly representative sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases then we can best help you. Bear in mind that an answer that produces the output you expect from some specific sample input is the starting point to getting a solution, not the end point, as robustness, efficiency, clarity, portability, etc. also have to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple grep pipeline that you can do, but it is a bit cumbersome to write down:

```
cut -f1 file1 | grep -Ff - file2  | grep -Ff - file3  | grep -Ff - file3  ...
```

Another way is using awk:

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a) if (a[i]==ARGC-1) print i}' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

The latter assumes that the id's are unique per file.

If they are not unique, it is a bit more tricky:

```
awk '(FNR==1){delete b}!($1 in b){a[$1]++;b[$1]}END{for(i in a) if (a[i]==ARGC-1) print i }' file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a list of all the ids in a file ids_list.txt with each ID being on a single line like

```
 id001
 id101
 id201
  ...
```

And all the files from which you want to search from are in the folder data . So in this scenario, this little script should be able to help you

```
#!/bin/bash
all_ids="";
for i in `cat ids_list.txt`; do
    all_ids="$all_ids|$i"
done
all_ids=`echo $all_ids|sed -e 's/^|//'`
grep -Pir "^($all_ids)[\s,]+" data
```

It output would be like

```
data/f1:id001, ssd
data/f3:id201, some data
...
```

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the issues with it.

Comment: @EdMorton Basically the script works fine. shelcheck.net is advising to use brackets instead of backticks and while loop instead of the for loop. Substituting backticks with brackets is no issue at all, but if we use while loop instead of the for loop, then variable scope issue will kick in as a while loop runs in its own sub-shell.

Comment: It must also be warning you about the missing quotes at least. Wrt a while loop requiring a subshell - no, it doesn't if written correctly (i.e. not reading from a pipe). Try `while read i; do all_ids="$all_ids|$i"; done < ids_list.txt` and see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for details. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why not to use a shell read loop for this at all though.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're trying to do but without sample input/output it's an untested guess:

```
awk '
    !seen[FILENAME,$1]++ {
        cnt[$1]++
    }
    END {
        for (id in cnt) {
            if ( cnt[id] == (ARGC-1) ) {
                print id
            }
        }
    }
' list file*
```